# How do I customize the content of model that is generated in Rails when I use scaffold generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, generator

- Command Used

  rails generate scaffold student firstname:string lastname:string

Generated Model Code is

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname
end
```

================================================================================

All my models should have following when the scaffold or the model is generated

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
  acts_as_tenant(:tenant)
  attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname
end
```

So when I generate the models using the generators, the lines such as resourcify and acts_as_tenant are already present in the models that get generated and I do not need to include these manually in the models.

Can someone please guide me in how to achieve the same?

Regards,
Dkat.

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible with scaffolding

you can create rake task or shell script to gsub

```
attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname
```

to

```
resourcify
acts_as_tenant(:tenant)
attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname
```

in all model's files

as far as it happening [here](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding) when you need to add `#encoding: utf-8` to all files

Comment: Hello okliv..Thanks for this solution. I have followed your suggestion of creating the rake task and solved the issue right now. However, this only means that when someone creates the scaffolding, they have to execute the rake tasks later. I had thought that we could customize the rails generator - which might have been a better solution.Regards, Dkat

Answer (score 0):

after running the following command in terminal 
rails generate scaffold student firstname:string lastname:string

go to the migration file which present in the db directory.
edit that file.. 
that may solve your problem..